# Rails has_many :through association with accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm struggling with accepts_nested_attributes_for for a many-to-many association. I have offers which can have many catalogs and a catalog can be added to many offers. The models:

```
class Offer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :catalog_offer_memberships
  has_many :catalogs, through: :catalog_offer_memberships
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :catalog_offer_memberships
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :catalogs
end

class Catalog < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :catalog_offer_memberships
  has_many :offers, through: :catalog_offer_memberships
end

class CatalogOfferMembership < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :catalogs
  has_many :offers
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :catalogs
end
```

Now I hoped that after ...

```
catalog = Catalog.create
Offer.create(catalogs_attributes:[{ id: catalog.id }])
```

... Rails does all the work for me and creates the CatalogOfferMembership with the catalog_id and offer_id. But I got:

`raise_nested_attributes_record_not_found!': Couldn't find Catalog with ID=3 for Offer with ID= (ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound)``

And I thought, after creating the setup "manually" with:

```
offer = Offer.create
CatalogOfferMembership.create(offer_id: offer.id, catalog_id: catalog.id)
```

I can manipulate the offer's catalogs with:

```
Offer.first.update(catalogs_attributes:[{id: catalog.id, _destroy: true}])
```

Then I got no error, but the CatalogOfferMembership continues to exist.

How can I update the catalogs list for the offer during creating or updating the offer itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of passing the catalog in nested attributes, you should pass it in the association.

```rb
catalog = Catalog.create
Offer.create(catalogs: [catalog])
```

Also, the `CatalogOfferMembership` should have a reference to catalogs and offers with `belongs_to`.

```rb
class CatalogOfferMembership < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :catalog
  belongs_to :offer
end
```

Explanation: The nested attributes are either for creating associated models on creation (these ones are without ID) or updating already associated models' attributes. In your case, you could simplify the call with:

```rb
# This creates an offer, a catalog and the association between them
Offer.create(catalogs_attributes: [{  }])
```

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Regarding the removal of the `CatalogOfferMembership`, it can be achieved by setting the `dependent` option on the `has_many :catalog_offer_memberships` in both the offer and the catalog.

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#dependent

Comment: Thanks for your help. So the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` stuff is not necessary here. I do not want to update/create/destroy catalogs through the offer. I only want to change the offer's associated catalogs.